# Advance usage of Context Menu

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have read a variety of context menu tutorials, and most of them are quite simple and cannot be further modified, for example, every time I click the menu in Unity Editor to make the player score go up by 10 will be like.

```
    [ContextMenu("Add Score By 10")]
    public void addScore01()
    {
        playerScore = playerScore + 10;
    }
```

let say if i want to add the player score by specific amount, the same way how i use it when i call this method

```
    public void addScore(int scoreToAdd)
    {
        playerScore = playerScore + scoreToAdd;

    }
```

Can the context menu work like that, and if so, what the code would be like?

One more question, if I want to spawn something (e.g.  Instantiate some gameobject), can the context menu handle Instantiate as well?

```
   Spawn1BlockStore(RefPoint, BlockWidth);
```

Would really love to learn the usage and limitation of the Unity context menu, the manual page is so simple I hardly understand what it can or cannot do.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ContextMenu.html

Answer (score 1):

Elements in context menu are just buttons, so execution can't be parametrized from context menu.

Probably easiest way to achieve this type of functionality would be to use some Unity inspector asset that adds buttons to monobehaviours. This would allow you to create "debug" gameobject with different functions with custom parameters. (Like NaughtyAttributes or Odin Inspector)